# Matlab size function datatype output?

Tags: arrays, matlab, types

For some reason when I try the `size` function in matlab, I cannot determine the datatype and cannot use it the way I want.

```
data = [[3,4,56,1,2],[3,1,3,45,2]];
```

Then, I want to get the second dimension:

```
size(data)(2)
```

throws an error:

```
>> size(data)(2)
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Then I try this:

```
>> n = size(data)

n =

     1    10

>> n(2)

ans =

    10
```

And it is no problem.  Blows my mind.  why?  and, what type of data type does `size` return?

Comment: Interestingly, octave has no problem with `size(data)(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `size(data,2)`. This is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

That is not allowed in MATLAB, as your error says.
To use the size function on a multi-dimensional array (matrix), use `size(data, 1)` to get the number of rows and `size(data, 2)` to get the number of columns.

Here is the (first bit of the) result from `help size` on MATLAB.

```
>>help size
'size' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/data.cc

 -- Built-in Function: size (A)
 -- Built-in Function: size (A, DIM)

 Return the number of rows and columns of A.

 With one input argument and one output argument, the result is
 returned in a row vector.  If there are multiple output arguments,
 the number of rows is assigned to the first, and the number of
 columns to the second, etc.
```

Similarly, if you have a matrix `A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6]`, use the same method to access the elements. For example, `A(1,1) = 1` (NOT A(1)(1)), and `A(2,2) = 5`.

Cheers!

**EDIT:**
Also, did you mean `data = [[3,4,56,1,2];[3,1,3,45,2]];` (notice the semi-color separating the rows)? Because `data = [[3,4,56,1,2],[3,1,3,45,2]];` would return a long 10-dimensional vector instead of a 5x2 matrix.

Comment: I think you meant "NOT `A(1)(1)`"? :)

Comment: @jadhachem: Yep! That's what I mean, fixed it btw.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys.  However, as I said in my question, it isn't clear to me why it works to index like `(1,1)`, but it doesn't work to index in two separate operations, like shown in my question.  Is there a good explanation?